# Lookup weird behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11

c++ ADL lookup is running when normal lookup fails, in this example i get error about ambiguous g call. I think that normal lookup should only find B::g. Why i am wrong?

```
namespace A
    {
        struct X{
        };

        struct Y{
        };

        void g(X){
        }
        void h(){

        }

    }

    namespace B
    {
        void g(A::X x);
        void g(A::X x) { g(x);}

    }
```

error:

```
error: call to 'g' is ambiguous
    void g(A::X x) { g(x);  }
                     ^
c0202.cpp:9:10: note: candidate function
    void g(X){
         ^
c0202.cpp:20:10: note: candidate function
    void g(A::X x) { g(x);  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> c++ ADL lookup is running when normal lookup fails

No, argument-dependent lookup always happens alongside normal lookup. That's kind of the point.

Suppose you have

```
struct S { /* ... */ };
void swap(S &, S &) { /* ... */ }
```

You wouldn't want standard library functions (defined in the `std` namespace) to be unable to find this user-defined `swap` function, would you? They'll always be able to see `std::swap`, because they themselves are part of the `std` namespace, yet they may still prefer your `::swap` found by ADL.